# How to handle Histogram "Spike"

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, histogram, data-preprocessing

This dataset is motor insurance premiums for 4 insurers.

25K observations were made using different combinations of features (make, model, driver age, at fault accident, etc).

In this plot y-axis is n_experiments, x-axis is premium (binned).

The first 3 insurers have a spike in the top bin. I assume this means "all premiums above $375". Is that a fair assumption?

Will these spikes impact the accuracy of the model?

If it is a problem, how would you normally treat this? Dropping the some of the rows to achieve a more 'normal' distribution?

**[Edit: Added the code and data]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

#load the data
df = pd.read_csv('simple_data.csv')

#Remove outliers
#df = df[df['INSURER1_PREMIUM'] < 386]

#Linear Regression
X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
y = df[df.columns[-1:]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)

print('Linear Regression Train: ', reg.score(X_train, y_train))
print('Linear Regression Test: ', reg.score(X_test, y_test))

#Random Forrest
X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
y = df[df.columns[-1:]].values.ravel()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=15, min_samples_leaf=5, n_jobs=-1, random_state=1) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Random Forrest Train: ', r2_score(model.predict(X_train), y_train))
print('Random Forrest Test: ', r2_score(model.predict(X_test), y_test))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 18))
ax.axhline(y=0, color='red')
plt.xlabel('X_test index', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Residuals', fontsize=20)
plt.scatter(X_test.reset_index().index, (y_test - y_pred))
```

data: https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1wGSX_A6fiHRhQ6oD5ApBcw8VwqRjNNPP

[image]

[image: Residuals Plot]

Comment: What kind of model are you making? The answer to your question will depend on domain knowledge specific to your field, as well as the goal that you would like to achieve with this data.

Comment: I have run a couple of algorithms from SKLearn. Linear Regression resulting in R2 = 68 and Random Forrest resulting in R2 = 95+%

Comment: If those are out-of-sample scores, then you’re doing really well! Certainly this is task-dependent, but out-of-sample $R^2=0.95$ sounds like quite strong performance. Also, remember that the standard assumptions in OLS have to do with the error term, not the predictors or the response variable.

Comment: Yes. The Random forrest result is fine but the Linear Regression result is not good. That's not my question though. I am really wondering about what effect do the "outlier" values (i.e. the spikes in the 375 bin) have? And how would they normally be handled?

Comment: What do the residuals of your linear model look like?

Comment: MAE: 27.932969567789385 MSE: 1646.6575370238438 RMSE: 40.579028290779014

Comment: I meant a plot of the residuals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100841/discussion-between-dave-and-axle-max).